# Formatting Number in JQuery/JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating an app with Phonegap and JQuery Mobile and have a particular scenario where I need to format a particular counter.

Basically the counter starts from 1 and keeps increasing when a certain event is triggered.  However, in order to display it i need to display them as 0001 then once an event is triggered it goes to 0002 .... 0099... 0999... 9999 (max).

So far what I have is outputting the number such as 15, but I cannot find how to put the 00 padding in front so that the value is always displayed as 4 characters.

Can someone help me or direct me to any plugin available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To format your number, you could do

```
var formattedNumber = ("000"+number).slice(-4);
```

EDIT following comment :

You can do this :

```
 var eventCounter = parseInt($('.eventCount').text(), 10) +1;
 $('.eventCount').text(("000"+number).slice(-4));
```

Don't forget the second argument to [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), the radix, as `parseInt("0009")` is `0`...

But I'd suggest to use an id and not a class as selector : this would be faster as you have only one div. So your HTML would be

```
<div id=eventCount>0001</div>
```

And your jQuery selector would be `"#eventCount"` instead of ".eventCount".

Comment: so far I have this:

var eventCounter = parseInt($('.eventCount').html());
$('.eventCount').text(eventCounter+1);

Do you have any suggestions on how to do it?  Sorry im still new to JQuery and JS altogether..

Comment: is there any other option to use other than parseInt then?

all i need to do is eventCounter++ as such.

Comment: parseInt is fine if you precise the radix as in my answer but you can keep your variable separately by defining `var eventCounter=1` in the global scope.

Comment: I replaced the number by (eventCounter+1) as it wasn't working.  I also changed the html to have IDs rather than classes as you suggested.  So the final code is:

JS:
 var eventCounter = parseInt($('#eventCount').text(), 10) +1;
 $('#eventCount').text(("000"+(eventCounter+1)).slice(-4));  

HTML:
<div id=eventCount>0001</div>

Seems to work!  Thanks a lot :)